# TeXForm and Symbolize

Tags: symbols, latex

I would like to use `TeXForm` to generate LaTeX output as usual. However, I use subscripted variables such as `c_t`. Unfortunately, when using `Symbolize` from the package `Notation` for this end, `TeXForm` does not work as expected. While I expected output such as c_t, I receive:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];
TeXForm[c<Ctrl>_t]<Shift+Enter>

\text{c$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$Subscript$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$t}.
```

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps
 `StringReplace`?

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: `StringReplace[yourSymbolizedVariable // ToString, StringExpression[b : __, "\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]", e : __] :> StringJoin["Subscript[", b, ",", e, "]"]] // ToExpression // TeXForm`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Adding `TraditionalForm` for symbolized expressions

When you load `` Notation` `` package it automatically assigns definitions to `MakeExpression` and `MakeBoxes` function. Those definitions call `NotationMakeExpression` and `NotationMakeBoxes` functions respectively.

After symbolizing expression with a pattern, special definition is assigned to `NotationMakeExpression` function. This definition forces Mathematica to perform some tasks when expression, matching symbolized pattern, is encountered.
A symbol, with name reflecting symbolized expression, is constructed, then special rules for this symbol are assigned to `NotationMakeBoxes`. These rules tell Mathematica what is box representation of constructed symbol in `StandardForm`.

Since only definitions for `StandardForm` are added, specially constructed symbol looks like symbolized expression in `StandardForm` and possibly other forms that use `StandardForm` boxes, but not in other forms.

`TeXForm` uses boxes from `TraditionalForm` not `StandardForm`. To solve your problem in general way for all symbolized subscripted expressions you could inspect `NotationMakeBoxes` definition and assign correct `TraditionalForm` to all symbols that have `SubscriptBox` assigned to `StandardForm`.

Let's define some functions that will do this automatically.
We start with function that converts boxes in `StandardForm` to boxes in `TraditionalForm`:

```
SetAttributes[standardToTraditionalBoxes, HoldAllComplete]
standardToTraditionalBoxes[boxes_] := 
    Function[expr, MakeBoxes[expr, TraditionalForm], HoldAllComplete] @@
        MakeExpression[boxes, StandardForm]
```

Now a function converting `NotationMakeBoxes` down value to proper `MakeBoxes` definition for `TraditionalForm`:

```
addSubscriptTraditionalForm[
    Verbatim[HoldPattern][
        Verbatim[Condition][
            Notation`NotationMakeBoxes[sym_Symbol, StandardForm],
            _
        ]
    ] :>
        SubscriptBox[x_, y_]
] := (
        sym /: MakeBoxes[sym, TraditionalForm] = 
            SubscriptBox[standardToTraditionalBoxes[x],standardToTraditionalBoxes[y]]
    )
```

And final function traversing down values:

```
updateSubscriptTraditionalForm[] := 
   Scan[addSubscriptTraditionalForm, DownValues[Notation`NotationMakeBoxes]]
```

`updateSubscriptTraditionalForm` function should be evaluated after all symbolized expressions were read by Mathematica and before using `TeXForm`.

### Small test

Load `` Notation` `` and symbolize all expressions with subscripts:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

Now some strange test expression:

> f[a + b]<sub>Sin[c]</sub>

in `FullForm` gives:

```
f\[UnderBracket]LeftBracket\[UnderBracket]a\[UnderBracket]Plus\[UnderBracket]b\[UnderBracket]RightBracket\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]Sin\[UnderBracket]LeftBracket\[UnderBracket]c\[UnderBracket]RightBracket
```

in `TeXForm`, before evaluating `updateSubscriptTraditionalForm`, gives:

```
\text{f$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$LeftBracket$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$a$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$Plus$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$b$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$RightBracket$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$Subscript$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$Sin$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$LeftBracket$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$c$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$RightBracket}
```

and after `updateSubscriptTraditionalForm` evaluation, `TeXForm` gives:

```
f(a+b)_{\sin (c)}
```

---

## Old answer using `TeXUtilities` package

After using `Symbolize` c<sub>t</sub> looks in `FullForm` like this:

```
c\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]t
```

So result you're getting is a "correct" translation to TeX of above expression.

```
c\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]t//TeXForm
(* \text{c$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$Subscript$\mathsym{\UnderBracket}$t} *)
```

To get desired result you can add formatting rule to this expression using my [TeXUtilities package](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities).

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/NoInstall.m"]
Format[c\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]t, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim["c_t"];

c\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]t//TeXForm
(* c_t *)
```

Comment: Can I tell it to consider this the general formatting rule for subscripts?

Comment: @user191919 Unfortunately no. `Format` needs to assign formatting to specific symbols and after symbolization each expression with subscript is a separate symbol. But I've edited my answer and added different approach which should solve general problem.

Answer (score 5):

As @jkuczm says, [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) is based on [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm). So, use the [`WorkingForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/ref/WorkingForm)  option to [`Symbolize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/ref/Symbolize) to get it to work with [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm):

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_","_"]], WorkingForm->TraditionalForm]
```

Then:

```
Subscript[c, t] //TeXForm
```

> c_t

Comment: This did the trick for me. For some reason the @jkuczm answer threw an error.