# Using TeXForm for subscripted variables

Tags: symbols, latex, notation

I tried following the answer in [TeXForm and Symobilze](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72064/texform-and-symbolize), however, I have trouble making it work. I loaded the Notation packages and symbolized all expressions with a subscript as in the example. I defined the same test function using Ctrl+_, I do obtain the same output for TeXForm and FullForm before loading updateSubscriptTraditionalForm[]. However, after loading it, TeXForm still gives me the same output?

Comment: I added an alternate answer to that question that may help you.

Comment: That's great! It causes a new problem though, but it answers this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimentation, it would seem that using StandardForm inside TeXForm works, all the while keeping the WorkingForm default:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]

TeXForm[StandardForm[Subscript[a, 1]]]
```

Instead of just`TeXForm[Subscript[a, 1]]`. I am not sure why/how, but it works.