# Notation package with Traditional Form

Tags: replacement, custom-notation, subscript

I symbolize subscripted variables with the form TraditionalForm, to enable easy use of TeXForm as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72064/texform-and-symbolize):

```
 Needs["Notation`"]
 Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]], 
 WorkingForm -> TraditionalForm]
```

However: note the following example:

```
rule = f -> ftest;
Subscript[f, a] /. rule
```

The rule replaces the "f" in Subscript[f,a]. This is of course not wanted, as I want to treat f and Subscript[f,a] as different entities.
If I do not use the WorkingForm on TraditionalForm, this works as expected, but now for some reason, it has this behaviour???

Comment: What is `ftest`?

Comment: @Kuba Oh, a pure function in my code, such as: Function[{x},func[x]], and similarly Subscript[f,a] is really Subscript[f,a][x], but the example given here works as is, treating the rule like a change of label. At least, I presume that the problem is the same regardless?

Comment: With the notation package, your input form and output form should both be the same.  Try `Subscript[f, a] /. rule`, then before executing, use ctrl-t to change your input line to traditional form and then execute.

Comment: I tried: TraditionalForm[Subscript[f, a]] /. rule,   however this did not solve it I am afraid

Comment: That doesn't work for me either, but ctrl-shift-t does.

Comment: The reason is when you say `TraditionalForm[Subscript[f, a] /. rule]` you are specifying the output to be traditional form, which you already did in your symbolize statement.  To work, your input has to be traditional form before you execute it, which you can specify with ctrl-shift-t while your cursor is on your input line.

Comment: But, I only applied TraditionalForm on the Subscript, before applying the rule?
Nonetheless, I tried your suggestion and I obtain:
          f\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]a
 instead. Whereas, I I just want Subscript[f,a]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to explain with a GIF:

[image]

If you always need `TraditionalForm` of output,

1. If you're before *v11.1*, set it in **Edit**->**Preferences**->**Evaluation**->**Format type of new output cells**.
2. If you're in or after *v11.1*, execute `SystemOpen@"init.m"` to open the init.m file and save `$PrePrint = TraditionalForm;` in it. (There's a design change in *v11.1*, for more information check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140309/1871). )

Comment: By applying //FullForm , it seems that it then treats the "Ctrl+Shift+t" symbol a_1 very much differently. Usually, I would just get Subscript[a,1], while here, I now get: a[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]1 instead?? Does this mean that it treats them as different variables?

Comment: @Patrick.B There seems to be a design change in _v11.1_: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140309/1871 In principle a solution is Ctril+Shift+O, then Cell Options ► New Cell Defaults ► CommonDefaultFormatTypes, but this doesn't work in _11.2_ on my PC. Anyway, `$PrePrint = TraditionalForm;` works, you may place it in `SystemOpen@"init.m"`.

Comment: @Patrick.B Yes, notation package doesn't make _Mathematica_ treat `Subscript[a,1]` as a symbol, it just internally creates a symbol `a\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]1` and make it diplay as $a_1$ in the front end.

Comment: For the troublesome equation I was exporting using [TeXport](https://github.com/sgbaird/TeXport), writing out e.g., `Subscript[a,1]` explicitly rather than using `Ctrl+_` allowed it to format correctly.